# django logging is not coming to log file

Tags: django

django logging configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': { },
        'setting':{
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

error in debug.log:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Waiting for apps ready_event.
Apps ready_event triggered. Sending autoreload_started signal.
Watching dir /home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/locale with glob **/*.mo.
Watching dir /home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/locale with glob **/*.mo.
Watching dir /home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/locale with glob **/*.mo.
Watching dir /home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/locale with glob **/*.mo.
Watching dir /home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/locale with glob **/*.mo.
Watching dir /home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/locale with glob **/*.mo.
Watching dir /home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/locale with glob **/*.mo.
Watching dir /home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/locale with glob **/*.mo.
Watching dir /home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/user/locale with glob **/*.mo.
Watching dir /home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/corsheaders/locale with glob **/*.mo.
(0.001) QUERY = 'SELECT "django_migrations"."app", "django_migrations"."name" FROM "django_migrations"' - PARAMS = (); args=()
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Waiting for apps ready_event.
Apps ready_event triggered. Sending autoreload_started signal.
```

error i am expecting:

```
File "/home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 552, in collection_names
    ReadPreference.PRIMARY) as (sock_info, slave_okay):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
File "/home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 904, in _socket_for_reads
    with self._get_socket(read_preference) as sock_info:
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
File "/home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 868, in _get_socket
    server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
File "/home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 214, in select_server
    address))
File "/home/fractaluser/Desktop/Dev/consumerhub/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 189, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 10.4.9.25:80: timed out
```

Above error is coming in my console but, it is not writing in my debug.log file.
It is only writing some basic things instead of actual error.

I have shared my settings conf for logger and log file.

Answer (score 0):

Please Add this in your logging:

```
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level': 'WARN',
    },
    'django.db.backends': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    }
```